# htaccess and cakephp - whats the correct path/to/app in this situation

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I'm trying to install cakephp on a 1&1 account but running into problems.

I believe I need to add

```
RewriteBase /path/to/cake/app
```

to the htaccess file but I can't figure out what the path should be.

I have put the cakephp files in a folder called scissors on the most bottom level of folders I can browse to using filezilla. With that in mind I tried

```
RewriteBase /scissors/app
```

but that didn't work. What should it be?

**EDIT**:

I have managed to get the site to work (sort of) but unfortunately the css doesn't seem to get loaded.
The three htaccesses which I have which are working but not pulling the css are:

in /scissors

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteBase /app
       RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
       RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

in scissors/app

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /app/
        RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
        RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

in scissors/app/webroot

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /app/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't correctly loading the css?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answer is for cake 2.0 and I'm assuming that you've unzipped downloaded archive inside your public_html, so the path to cake looks like

```
/home/your_login/public_html/scissors/files_and_folders_unzipped_here
```

Or just

```
/public_html/scissors/files_and_folders_unzipped_here
```

as

```
/home/your_login
```

may not be visible.

Inside "scissors" folder (where app, lib, plugins, vendors etc folders are) place .htaccess with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Inside "app" folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$   webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

And inside "webroot" folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

There is one more way to install cake (allows to have multiple sites on one "core config") but unzipping everything inside public folder is the easiest one.

Comment: What's your path to cake folder?

Comment: Go to index.php inside webroot, uncomment line _define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib');_. Then change it to _define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH',  DS . 'home' . DS . 'your_login' . DS . 'public_html' . DS . 'scissors' . DS . 'lib');_. Hard to say what exacly it should contain without knowledge about your full path.

Comment: And, well, get rid of RewriteBase, I gave you working examples, with those RewriteBase I'm not sure if it's gonna work, unless you know what you're doing

Comment: Hey erem, thanks for you help with this :) I tried your solution above with the different htaccess's but I just end up with a 500 error. I've found out the path from my host - /kunden/homepages/9/d121020121/htdocs/scissors/app - and I added that to index.php in scissors/app/webroot like you said but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Basically if I use the htaccess files I posted in my edit in the Qu it works. It's just there's no css styles and in the view->source the call to get css is <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/cake.generic.css" /> I guess this is supposed to be href="/scissors/css/cake.generic.css"

Comment: I tried your solution but it gives me: Fatal error: CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to the directory containing your /cake core directory and your /vendors root directory. in /opt/lampp/htdocs/carte_drin/app/webroot/index.php on line 102